# Why am I getting the terminal error "try apt-get -f install"?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

Okay, I just install Ubuntu (the LXDE version, which is Lubuntu) and everytime I try to install a package through the terminal with the "Apt-get install" command, this error pops up:

```
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages
```

And, yes this is for every package i try to install. When I do `apt-get -f install`
this is the terminal output I receive:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc-bin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc-bin
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,168 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,532 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Could someone please help me? I just started using linux 2 months ago, and switched to Lubuntu.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1266104.html this may help you..

Comment: Can you post the ouput of `sudo echo $PATH`?

Comment: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

Comment: What version of Ubuntu did you install? The problem is that libc-bin is missing, there was an old bug in 2011 that could cause this error - if you did install such an old version, it would be better to re-install 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before anything, try

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Just to get that out of the way so we know it's not that.

Then, try these commands, if you normally use sudo su then do not execute that command and do type sudo before every other command listed. If you normally typed sudo apt-get -f install, then execute these commands as listed.

```
sudo su
apt-get update
apt-get autoremove
apt-get autoclean
apt-get upgrade
```

And even if the last command fails try

```
apt-get -f install
```

For some reason using sudo su can be different than using sudo in terms of your $PATH.

Comment: I can't believe it but it worked. But only when root. I decided to reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat `sudo -s` does not use the same path see here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=983645&s=489a32d9679bc5a7b667e4f2c11da3f3&p=6188826#post6188826 the reason this works is because `sudo su` uses HOME=/root and whereas `sudo` and `sudo -s` use HOME=/home/username

Comment: actually the difference is the PATH and not HOME

Comment: Why do you need the root path for those commands?

Comment: @Whaaaaaat dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable